# Error trying to start mysql and can't preinstall it on linux

Tags: linux, mysql, ssh

I completed the steps needed to uninstall mysql completely and somehow mysql is always there even when I uninstall all of the packages. Not to mention that whether I am trying to run mysql, it fails due to this error : https://prnt.sc/fp14en

So I am stuck here, help please

Comment: Your external link may die before this question, and it only contains text. Please try to attach it as text; indent by four spaces to make it a code block.

Comment: Check `/var/log/mysql/error.log` and your service provider's logs (usually via `service mysql status`.

Comment: There is no error in the screenshot?

Answer (score -1):

Two things you can try:

```
# mysql -h localhost 
# mysql -h localhost -u root
```

To completely remove mysql do:

```
#  apt-get remove  mysql-server-5.5
```

Comment: `remove` will not remove the mysql server completely. This will not help with troubleshooting either.